# Copy Pasting Range of varying length from one worksheet to another worksheet using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, copy-paste

I have data that is set up to output as follows:

- 4 columns of data
- then the data is separated by 4 blank columns and then there are another 4 columns of data etc.
- The rows differ in length
- The data is pulled in from Bloomberg and so the rows may change every time the data is refreshed.
- The data starts at row 3 and column 2.

[image]

I am trying to create a loop that

- selects the entire 4 columns, copies and pastes them in another worksheet
- then moves across the 4 blank columns, copies the data and pastes it in the other worksheet right below the previously pasted data
- until the last column with data is reached.
- I'm trying to create a blank row in between each, and am also trying to keep the 4 columns next to each other when I pasted them into the new worksheet

[image]

Here is the code I am having trouble with....

```
Sub CopyPasteDex()

  Dim wksDest             As Worksheet
  Dim wksSource           As Worksheet
  Dim Rngsource           As Range
  Dim NextRow             As Long
  Dim LastRow             As Long
  Dim LastCol             As Long
  Dim c                   As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wksSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wksDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")

With wksDest
    NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

With wksSource
    LastCol = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For c = 2 To LastCol Step 7
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rngsource = .Range(.Cells(3, c), .Cells(LastRow, c + 3))
        Rngsource.Copy
        wksDest.Range("A:A").PasteSpecial.xlPasteValues
        NextRow = NextRow + Rngsource.Rows.Count
    Next c
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please define what "I am having trouble" means exactly.   Are you getting an error?   If no error but unexpected results, then add an example of the results you are getting, and the results you are trying to get instead.

Comment: Only problem I see is your `PasteSpecial` line.  After `PasteSpecial` there should be a space, then `xlPasteValues`, not a period.

Comment: For some reason, The macro is going across and copying the rest of the columns. It only copies and pastes the first set of 4. Also, thanks for that Darell

Comment: Uploaded images of the source and destination sheets respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This seems to work for me.

```
Sub CopyPasteDex()

  Dim wksDest             As Worksheet
  Dim wksSource           As Worksheet
  Dim Rngsource           As Range
  Dim NextRow             As Long
  Dim LastRow             As Long
  Dim LastCol             As Long
  Dim c                   As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wksSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wksDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")

With wksDest
    NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

With wksSource
    LastCol = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For c = 2 To LastCol Step 8    ' make sure that the step is changed to 8 here.
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rngsource = .Range(.Cells(3, c), .Cells(LastRow, c + 3))
        Rngsource.copy
        wksDest.Cells(NextRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues    ' Note that I've changed .range to .cells and changed the destination row to NextRow
        NextRow = NextRow + Rngsource.Rows.Count
    Next c
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Chris, attached an image to your comment. I tried your code and for some reason it pasted the info on the blank sheet in row 111. I tried it many times, and initially it pasted in row 65 or something and everytime I would delete and try again it would paste 20-30 rows further down..Also it isn't copying the rest of the data in the other columns. stays stuck at the first 4

Comment: I've just tried it again with my data and it worked perfectly. It starts pasting in at row 2 and adds the rest of the data below the data it's already pasted in.

Comment: That is really odd. Is the data 4 blank columns apart? Also is the loop working (is the data copying the four columns and pasting it in a new sheet then moving to the next four columns and copying it then pasting it under the previously pasted data?)

Comment: My data starts in with a heading in cell B3, and then B4:E23, next header at J3, data in J4:M15, and so on. That's why I changed the step in your loop to 8 rather than 7.

Comment: that sounds about right for me too, very weird why it isn't working for me. What do you think it might be?

Comment: It is now working! But for some reason, I get my start as row 184 when I first debug NextRow= .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1.

Comment: I'm not sure. Is your destination sheet ("Sheet2") empty? Did you change the PasteSpecial line as indicated above?

Comment: yes I did change it and destination sheet is empty!

Comment: Do you have 'Option Explicit' at the top of the module your code is in? I'm wondering if there's an obscure spelling mistake stopping your code from working.

Comment: yes sir I have that added, so I have no idea what is going on! Did you see the photo above to see what my data looks like? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, I looked at the photo and I have no idea what that's happening.

Comment: I've updated this to avoid copy/paste. I don't know if it will work for you.

Comment: unfortunately that isn't working for me. The old code was better in that it was performing everything with some errors. Do you mind reposting it so I can play around with it some more? Thanks again

Comment: Rolled back. I'm still at a loss as to why it's not working.

Comment: It is now working! I deleted the sheet and re-added and it now works!

Comment: I want the data to be pasted with a one row break in between each group of data, any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: Use `NextRow = NextRow + Rngsource.Rows.Count + 1`

Comment: Thanks!  Much appreciated